# Select Options: Build dropdown list of users

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm going crazy here.

I'm just trying to build a list of certain users.  Easy right?  I've been looking everywhere, and now I'm infinitely more confused, especially where I 'build' the option.  See below.  PLEASE HELP.

```
public class MYCLASS {

    //String used for the Select Options for user id, in Client list
    public String selectedUser {get;set;}

    //List for select options on userId, in client list
    public List<selectOption> userIDList(){
        userIDs=[select ID, name FROM user where IsActive= true ORDER by name ASC];
        list<selectoption> UserIDList = new list<selectoption>();

        UserIDList .add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
        for(user a:userIds){
            UserIDList.add(new SelectOption(a.Id, a.Name));
        }
        return UserIDList;
    }    

    public CONTROLLER(ApexPages.standardController sc){  

        selectedUser='';

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do here? create a list of select options of users to be displayed in your visualforce page?

Comment: `userIdList` needs to have a getter - that will provide the list of selectOption to the VF page

Comment: Where you are struck exactly? Error messages?

Comment: Hey guys - I was stuck in various ways - initially, nothing was populating.  Then I looked through various other pages of people looking for help, and I went down a slippery slope of not working code.  I ended up fixing it.  @crop1645 was right, I need to get a getter.   Thank you for responding guys, I was LOSING my mind over something so simple.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

OK so.  I figured it out.  Hopefully this helps someone.

CLASS:

You place this code after the controller ends, like SO:

```
public Controller(apexpages.standardController sc){

somevariable = new variable__C();

}

     public List<selectOption> getuserIDList(){
    consultantIDs=[select ID, name FROM user where IsActive= true ORDER by name ASC];
     list<selectoption> UserIDList = new list<selectoption>();

            UserIDList .add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
        for(user a:consultantIds){
            UserIDList.add(new SelectOption(a.Id, a.Name));
            }
        return UserIDList;
     }
```

Notice the "getUserIDList"?  Well my list name is UserIDList, and my Page code is:

```
<apex:outputPanel>
             <apex:selectList value="{!selectedUser}" size ="1" multiselect="false" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!userIDList}" />
             </apex:selectList>
               </apex:outputPanel>
```

So it wasn't working for me for two reasons: 1- I placed my code in the wrong area in the Class.  2.  I had to add "get" to the beginning of the list for it to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation of the getter would be:

```
public List<SelectOption> userSelectOptionList {
   get {
      if (this.userSelectOptionList == null) {
         this.userSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption> ();
         this.userSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(' ','---Select---'));

         for (User u : [select id, name from User where isActive = true order by name asc])
           this.userSelectOtionList.add(new SelectOption(u.id,u.name));
      }
      return this.userSelectOptionList;
   }
   private set;
 }
```

Advantages:

1. It only queries the user list once (presumes your VF page doesn't add new users) and thus page is more responsive for some use cases. The pattern is helpful in other VF scenarios where a getter may be called more than once (such as when used in a apex:repeat).
2. Avoids extraneous variable `consultantIds`.
3. Using `a` for an iteration variable on Users is misleading as that often is associated with Accounts

Comment: Am afraid the point 1 is not true. If the get method is called twice, first time userSelectOptionList will be initialised and added 10 users lets say. Second time when the get is called, userSelectOptionList won't be initialised but will add 10 users again to the list making it 20. Thus for every gettter call, it adds 10 users in the same transaction.

Comment: The for loop should be within the if condition.

Comment: Super old but just got pinged, why put the `for` loop outside the `null` check block? You should only call that in the lazy load too, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - geez, no kidding, no wonder I didn't get any upvotes :-)